# Creating multiple of the same radio button group

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a list of inner class tripSeatPreference, I would like to create for each item in that list a new group of radio buttons. I have written my attempt below in the view, it does not work right now my index seems to be out of range in my for loop.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MVC_COMP1562.Models;

namespace MVC_COMP1562.ViewModels
{
    public class SeatPreferencesShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
        public float Total { get; set; }
        public List<tripSeatPreference> Preferences { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> SeatPreferenceOptions { get; set; }

        public class tripSeatPreference
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int? SeatPreferenceSelected { get; set; }
            public CartItem CartItem { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MVC_COMP1562.ViewModels.SeatPreferencesShoppingCartViewModel

<table class="table">

    @for(int i=0;i<Model.SeatPreferenceOptions.Count();i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>Model.Preferences[i].CartItem.Trip.Title)</td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var radio in Model.SeatPreferenceOptions)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Preferences[i].SeatPreferenceSelected, Model.Preferences[i].Id, new { id = Model.Preferences[i].Id })</td>
                <td><label for="@Model.Preferences[i].Id">@radio</label><td/>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping on `SeatPreferenceOptions` while inside the loop you are trying to get item from `SeatPreferences` using index of `SeatPreferenceOptions` collection which will obviously fail, as there can be items more or less in one of them, so change the loop from:

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.SeatPreferenceOptions.Count();i++)
```

to:

```
 @for(int i=0;i<Model.SeatPreferences.Count();i++)
```